# Redirecting a page to another while reporting 301

Tags: linux, .htaccess

I have a page at example.com/news.php. This page is already indexed by Google. I would like to ditch this page and instead use example.com/news.

So essentially I need to report 301 on news.php and also redirect any request to /news to news.php.

When I am using the below in .htaccess I am getting a redirect loop:

```
Redirect        301 /news.php   http://example.com/news
RewriteRule     ^news$  news.php [L]
```

How would I go about doing the desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /news\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /news [L,R=301]

RewriteRule     ^news/?$    news.php [L]
```

Edit as per your comment :

To redirect any php file , you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule     ^(.+)/?$    $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Great. Works like a charm! And if I now want to extend it to any *.php page, how do I do that?

Comment: starkeen, thanks so much! It works well, except that AJAX calls don't seem to pass post parameters. Any idea why?